# Fluid/Continuous image scroll for the Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have successfully created a full background image scrolling effect using a single image. The code I used to achieve this is like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BackGround Slide</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         // speed in milliseconds
         var scrollSpeed = 70;

         // set the default position
         var current = 0;

         // set the direction
         var direction = 'h';

         function bgscroll() {

             // 1 pixel row at a time
             current -= 1;

             // move the background with backgrond-position css properties
             $('body').css("backgroundPosition", (direction == 'h') ? current + "px 0" : "0 " + current + "px");

         }

         //Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
         setInterval("bgscroll()", scrollSpeed);
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/yhBqRw6.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This works as expected. However, there is a clear demarcation between the beginning and the end of the image. Is there a way to say, achieve a continuous effect wherein the image's beginning and end isn't so obvious. I mean, can this be achieved using CSS/JS or do I need to edit/modify the image itself?

This is what the current output looks like:

[image: Scroll Background]

Thank you

Comment: try background-size:100% 100% in the body class.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai, that's not continuous, maybe OP wants to keep original image size. Or to scroll it out of the original box.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai - That broke the image. Like so - http://i.imgur.com/wxgVxal.png

Comment: You could flip the image horizontally so that they appear to seam together.

Answer (score 0):

CSS & JS do not do such things.

You might be able to find a jQuery plugin or such, in a short search I haven't found one.

Editing the image should be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I gathered as much. One method I thought was to continually extend the original image along width - that tends to increase the image size and makes loading the page slow. Nonetheless, thanks for the sugesstion. I'll looks out for plugins too..

Comment: If you extend it with CSS or Javascript it doesn't increase image size, but the image might stop looking good at some point.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify the image. Here is a tutorial to make a Tiled Background image using photoshop:

http://designshack.net/articles/css/create-seamless-web-background-textures-in-minutes/

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use symmetric background please check with below background:

**CSS :**

```
 body {
        background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/C11AY.png');
    }
```